# How to draw a class diagram for this code?

Tags: android-studio

I'd like to draw a class diagram for this code.

I'm working on a project using Android Studio. I've tried, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. This is an Activity class code for STT

I picked parts where I'm uncertain about:

```
public class VoiceMain_Activity extends Activity {
//
};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /** Called TedPermission **/
    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Toast.makeText(VoiceMain_Activity.this, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            run();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(VoiceMain_Activity.this, "denined\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    };
    TedPermission.with(this)
            .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
            .setRationaleTitle(R.string.rationale_title)
            .setRationaleMessage(R.string.rationale_message)
            .setDeniedTitle("denied")
            .setDeniedMessage(
                    " on/off .")
            .setGotoSettingButtonText("Setting")
            .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            .check();
}
private RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {
    @Override public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        int step = (int)(rmsdB/7);
        setVolumeImg(step);
    }
    @Override public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(END);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtras(results);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

        finish();
    }
    @Override public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(READY);
    }
    @Override public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(END);
    }
    @Override public void onError(int error) {
        setResult(error);
    }
    @Override public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}
    @Override public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {}
    @Override public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {}
    @Override public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {}
};
```

here's the image
[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYlrX.jpg)
not sure if I drew these 3 parts correctly

```
private RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() 
 public void onPermissionGranted() 
 public void onPermissionGranted()
```

Comment: May we see the diagram that you have drawn? It does not have to be finished, but it is very helpful for us to see your progress and direction.

Comment: Agreed with halfer.  In addition, what classes have you identified?  What relationships are you trying to draw or resolve?  Perhaps even what do you think your class diagram will show.  A partial diagram, or work in progress may answer some of these questions easily.

Comment: This may be put on hold while it is effectively too broad, but if you can edit it to include your diagram, it can be reopened at that time.

Comment: I've posted an image of my class diagram for that activity. Thank you for your help